# Migrating program files and projects from windows7 to Ubuntu

Tags: 14.04, migration, fortran

Is it possible to import

- program files
- projects (C/C++ and fortran) files
- application software already saved or installed

from windows7 system and its desktop to Ubuntu 14.04 without any damage?

Answer (score 0):

If you install Ubuntu alongside Windows 7 (or if you replace it and have a backup before), you will keep your Windows data.

Whether you can actually keep the *project* setup, depends on how you managed your project in Windows 7. C, C++ and Fortran can all be compiled on Linux. You can't run your binaries (*.exe) on Ubuntu natively, but if you have the source code, you can still compile them.

If you used an IDE, which is available for both Windows and Linux (like Eclipse), you most likely just can import a project into the same IDE on Linux. However, if you used an IDE, which is only available for Windows, you won't be able to take your project setup to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to be more specific about which programs you were using. The files themselves are normally text, and can transfer over.  Project files are normally not text, and are sometimes compiler/linker specific. If you were already using a cross-platform IDE such as Eclipse, you might be well ahead of the game.  If you were using Microsoft Visual Studio, you'll probably have to recreate the projects.

Cross platform is something that is usually planned ahead of time.  It can be done, but often not until you have used both platforms first.  It's not easy, but there are always things you can do to make it easier, such as conditional statements that used predefined constants to know what to do.